# Problems with jquery image slider

Tags: jquery, slideshow

I've been trying to create a simple image slider using jQuery, but next/previous buttons turned out to be a problem. I don not know how to prevent all sorts of bugs and glitches caused by spamming them or pressing them a little too fast. Here is the code

http://jsfiddle.net/6tkquyn1/2/ ... Can anyone please help?

HTML

```
<div id="slider">
                        <div id="arrowleft" class="slidernav"></div>
                        <div id="arrowright" class="slidernav"></div>
                        <img class="slide" id="slide1" src="http://s27.postimg.org/rquk1bk37/slide1.jpg">
                        <img class="slide" id="slide2" src="http://s3.postimg.org/5baw2ey6b/slide2.jpg">
                        <img class="slide" id="slide3" src="http://s18.postimg.org/jej03064p/slide3.jpg">
                        <img class="slide" id="slide4" src="http://s22.postimg.org/ubbx4ev4h/slide4.jpg">
```

CSS

```
*{
         magin: 0px;
         padding: 0px;
        }

        #slider
        {
         height: 350px;
         width: 700px;
         border: solid black 2px;
         position: relative;
        }

        .slide
        {
         position: absolute;
         overflow: hidden;
         display: none;
        }

        .slidernav
        {
         z-index: 999;
         opacity: 0;
         position: absolute;
         cursor: pointer;
         transition: .5s;
        }

        .slidernav:hover
        {
         opacity: 0.8;
        }

        #arrowright
        {
         height: 350px;
         width: 70px;
         right: 0;
         background-image: url(http://s1.postimg.org/hx6atzftb/arrowright.png);
        }

        #arrowleft
        {
         height: 350px;
         width: 70px;
         left: 0;
         background-image: url(http://s22.postimg.org/5fn2unxu9/arrowleft.png);
        }
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){

            $("#slide1").show("fade",800);

            var interval;
            var counter = 1;
            var slideNumber = $("#slider img").size();

            function startSlider () {interval = setInterval(function(){

                                        $("#slide"+counter).hide("slide",{direction:"left"},800);

                                        if(counter==slideNumber){counter = 1;}
                                        else{counter = counter+1;}
                                        $("#slide"+counter).show("slide",{direction:"right"},800);},4800);}
            startSlider();

            function pauseSlider() {clearInterval(interval);}

            $(".slide").on("mouseover", pauseSlider).on("mouseleave", startSlider);

                    $('#arrowleft').click(
                    function () {
                    $('.slide').queue();
                    pauseSlider();
                    $('#slide'+ counter).hide("slide",{direction: "right"},800);
                    if(counter==1){counter = slideNumber;}
                    else{counter = counter-1;}
                    $('#slide'+ counter).show("slide",{direction: "left"},800);
                    startSlider();
                });

                $('#arrowright').click(
                    function () {
                    $('.slide').queue();
                    pauseSlider();
                    $('#slide'+ counter).hide("slide",{direction: "left"},800);
                    if(counter == slideNumber){counter = 1;}
                    else{counter = counter+1;}
                    $('#slide'+ counter).show("slide",{direction: "right"},800);
                    startSlider();
                });


        });
```

Comment: Can you be a little more specific about the undesirable behavior that is occurring and what exactly you would like to happen?

Comment: click one of the arrows several times and you'll see that the images are appearing before the previous ones hide. Also queue is building up and keeps animating long after you have clicked the arrows. I am right now trying to make the arrows unclickable while animations are running, but cant seem to succeed in that either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so you can fix this by testing to see whether the previous slide has fully transitioned out of view. You can test this with the jQuery: $(...).is(':visible'). There are a couple changes to your original code in here:

1) There is now a lastCounter, which keeps track of the slide that needs to be hidden before allowing the user to change slides. This is updated any time there is a transition of slides.

2) The slide changing callbacks now check to see whether the animation is complete before allowing the user to change the image again.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#slide1").show("fade", 800);

    var interval;
    var counter = 1;
    var lastCounter = 2;
    var slideNumber = $("#slider img").size();

    function startSlider() {
        interval = setInterval(function () {
            $("#slide" + counter).hide("slide", { direction: "left" }, 800);

            lastCounter = counter;
            if (counter == slideNumber) {
                counter = 1;
            } else {
                counter = counter + 1;
            }

            $("#slide" + counter).show("slide", { direction: "right" }, 800);
        }, 4800);
    }
    startSlider();

    function pauseSlider() {
        clearInterval(interval);
    }

    $(".slide").on("mouseover", pauseSlider).on("mouseleave", startSlider);

    $('#arrowleft').click(function() {
        if ($('#slide' + lastCounter).is(":visible")) {
            return;
        }

        $('.slide').queue();
        pauseSlider();
        $('#slide' + counter).hide("slide", { direction: "right" }, 800);
        lastCounter = counter;
        if (counter == 1) {
            counter = slideNumber;
        } else {
            counter = counter - 1;
        }
        $('#slide' + counter).show("slide", { direction: "left" }, 800);
        startSlider();
    });

    $('#arrowright').click(function() {
        if ($('#slide' + lastCounter).is(":visible")) {
            return;
        }

        $('.slide').queue();
        pauseSlider();
        $('#slide' + counter).hide("slide", { direction: "left" }, 800);
        lastCounter = counter;
        if (counter == slideNumber) {
            counter = 1;
        } else {
            counter = counter + 1;
        }
        $('#slide' + counter).show("slide", { direction: "right" }, 800);
        startSlider();
    });
});
```

Comment: Wow, you have put really great effort in fixing my code. Your code works like a charm. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Try using  the below in css

`*{
             magin: 0px;
             padding: 0px;
            }

```
        #slider
        {
         height: 350px;
         width: 700px;
         border: solid black 2px;
         position: relative;
        }

        .slide
        {
         position: absolute;
         overflow: hidden;
         display: none;
        }

        .slidernav
        {
         z-index: 999;
         opacity: 0;
         position: absolute;
         cursor: pointer;
         transition: .5s;
        }

        .slidernav:hover
        {
         opacity: 0.8;
        }

        #arrowright
        {
         height: 350px;
         width: 70px;
         left:440px;
         background-image: url(http://s1.postimg.org/hx6atzftb/arrowright.png);
        }

        #arrowleft
        {
         height: 350px;
         width: 70px;
         left: 0;
         background-image: url(http://s22.postimg.org/5fn2unxu9/arrowleft.png);
        }`
```

I just replaced "right: 0;" with "left: 440px;" in #arrowright. It is working now.